# SQL insert values lowercased and with underscores

Tags: mysql, insert, copy, lowercase

I've got a database with a list of names, but these names contain spaces and are capitalised.
How do I copy the name in each row and put it it back in each row but in a different column (lets say "name_url") after they have been lowercased and replaced the spaces with underscores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here,

```
UPDATE TableName
SET destinationCOlumn = LOWER(REPLACE(sourceColumn, ' ', '_'))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16302/1)